# Customizing Android in-app purchase UI

Tags: android, user-interface, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is there a way to customize the android in-app purchase UI?

[image]
the motivation is having a more consistent user experience.

Comment: No. Motivation is to have a more consistent purchase experience.

Comment: @323go well, that's not a "regular" purchase, and its part of the app identity. its more of billing rather than actual purchase.

Comment: As a consumer, I don't care about your app's identity. I want to recognize the screen that costs me money the moment it comes up.